# iOS App store review issue

Tags: angularjs

I was developed one mobile application using YouTube Data API. When I submit my app into App Store, I was getting the following review:

> Guideline 5.2.2 - Legal
>
> Your app contains various copyrighted movies or TV shows. The use of third-party copyrighted materials requires documented evidence of your right to use such content in your app.*
>
> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights, you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please provide documentary evidence of rights to use this content. Acceptable documentation includes a copy of your contract with the copyright holder or a letter from the copyright holder to your company, as COMPANY_NAME_HERE detailing your authorization. Please be sure to include dates, rights holders' names, your company's name, and relevant signatures. Once we have reviewed your documentation and confirmed its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.
>
> Alternatively, please remove the third-party content from your app and its metadata.

Can you please someone guide me, how to resolve the above issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: are you got the permisson for use the thirdparty content in your app

Comment: i was using the youtube data api and it is securable only. is there any procedure to use youtube data api in ios